# Is there a way to locale user folders without changing actual names?

Tags: 16.04, directory, locale

I recently came from Windows to Ubuntu 16.04.2 and can't figure something out. Is there a way to force Ubuntu to show localized names for user folders (in my case, Russian ones) – Downloads, Documents, etc, but with keeping their original names in English. Like it's implemented in Windows system, where all actual names are English, but you see them localized. The point is I want to see Russian names for these folders, but use original English ones in bash (it's stupid to jump from one keyboard layout to another while typing a command line). Sorry if this question was asked before. I searched hard, and as far as I can tell – I didn't find any appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create hard links for its directory. FOr example.

> ln     ~/Downloads/   ~/Desktop/Загрузки
>
> ln    ~/Documents  ~/Desktop/Документы

After if you will show this folders in your Desktop.